# MySQL error 1109 (Unknown table) when calling procedure

Tags: mysql

I have error-code 1109 in call procedure in MySQL.

```
Error Code: 1109
Unknown table 'chaindb.credit_trans' in field list
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we cannot help you except by explaining what the error message means, but I guess you know that already.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is telling you that in your database `chaindb` table `credit_trans` does not exist.

I suggest verifying that you have your table named correctly.  If you do indeed, then you will need to post more information.